# Casimir Functions of Poisson Structure

Tags: symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

I have just started to read Poisson Geometry and was working my way through some problems. This may be basic for many, but I am just trying to understand the way to work through it. The problem says:

Consider the expressions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for the Poisson bracket:
$\{x_1,x_2\}=x_3$, $\{x_2,x_3\}=x_1$, $\{x_3,x_1\}=x_2$, $\{x_i,x_j\}=-\{x_j,x_i\}$.

(a) Verify this is really a Poisson bracket.

(b) Can it be symplectic? (i.e. non-degenerate)

(c) Find a nontrivial Casimir function in case it is not symplectic.

Parts (a) and (b) are straightforward, and it is not symplectic since we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am a bit stuck as to how to compute the Casimir function in (c). What should be my line of thought here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a way that works in this case: try a polynomial of degree $1$, degree $2$, ...

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but can you please elaborate a little, if it is not a bother. Thanks.

Comment: Using the Poisson brackets of coordinates which you have, you [can calculate the Poisson bracket of arbitrary functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2953588/23180). The condition for $C$ to be a Casimir is equivalent to $\{x_i, C\} = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$. So calculate the left-hand sides for $C={}$ a polynomial with undetermined coefficients and solve the equations.

Comment: Ricardo, your comment and the reference was spot on. It worked out perfectly and also helped me to understand it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to write up the calculation and/or result as an answer to your question. By the way, this is the rigid body Poisson bracket on $\mathfrak{so}(3)^*$ (I didn't say it beforehand because it would have spoiled the exercise without explaining anything).